# How can anonymous users see html page in a side bar link in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I've created a side bar link for a job that allows users to see a html page which resides in the workspace. I have authentication setup as well in jenkins. If the user is not logged into jenkins, they are not able to view the page unless logged in. Is there a permission I need to change to allow anonymous users to see the html page?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how you have added a link the side bar?. Did you use the sidebar-link plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by checking Job > Workspace for Anonymous users under 'Configure Global Security'.